# Getting the actual value of an XML binding in C# from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's my XAML

```
<Label x:Name="fileName" Content="{Binding XPath=./name}" MouseDown="copyUrl" />
```

and here's my C# code

```
private void copyUrl(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Label lol = (Label)sender;

    string fileUrl = lol.Content.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(fileUrl);
}
```

I expect the output to be `data.txt` but I get `System.Xml.XmlElement` instead! What am I casting wrong or missing here?

Comment: If you can answer a question yourself, post it as an answer, in this case Craig Suchanec pretty much answered the question (albeit without providing the explicit code), i edited the core into his answer. Please accept it using the checkmark next to the post so this question is no longer officially counted as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your content from the `XmlElement` to a string or access its `InnerXml` property.  It is just doing an implicit `ToString()` on the bound item.

```
string fileUrl = ((sender as Label).Content as XmlElement).InnerText;
```

Comment: Edit: figured it! Updating original post.